# Touchpad response badly when connecting monitor

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cable, cursor

When I connect my laptop to a monitor through the HDMI connection, I have a hard time controlling the mouse using the touchpad.

I'll try to explain as best as I can:

The touchpad works perfectly fine until I plug in the HDMI cable, then the cursor moves jumpy, and response badly. It moves in the general direction I try to move it, but not in a straight line.

The behavior seems to be very similar to the one described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/76649/laptop-touchpad-works-incorrect-when-on-power-supply). However, in my case it's not the power supply that's the problem, it's the HDMI.

Does anyone know what the cause can be and if there is a solution?

My laptop is an Asus Zenbook ux32vd running on Windows 8

Comment: Can you verify that it is not a general poor speed of graphic rendering issue (cursers do go into hardware render, when drivers are properly installed)?   Other than the touchpad, does a HD movie play ok?  Do games work up to par for the equiptment?  Are all other aspects of the video working fine but the curser?

Comment: @Psycogeek, I can verify that I don't have any problems with the graphics. I haven't tried gaming, but high def videos work fine.

Comment: I Might find it time to use one of the "latency checker" softwares , and see if it spotted anything. Sometimes the Extra parts of a touchpad driver are a "process" that can be controlled.  If you know of its process you could attempt to put it into High Priority in a task manager.  It would be interesting to see the "Gpu load" (ammount of work the gpu is doing), I would only know how to do that for my own puter.   Use the resource monitor and check for both CPU use & cpu frequency, there is one type of power profile in windows that can act like cpu throttling.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with the same computer. I have found that the problem is more tolerable if you set the pointer speed to a smaller value, as if the amplitude of the jumps gets smaller. (Control Panel > Mouse Properties > Pointer options > Motion > Select a pointer speed). I haven´t found a real solution.
Guillermo

Answer (score 0):

i 've been solved this problem !
Problem is the wire connecting between my laptop and monitor,i just replace it by another different.everything 's OK.Hope this help everyone !

Comment: While it's a nice effort are you sure it was the same problem?

Comment: i thinks the cause both with the monitor's power supply,might be adapter..I replace by new monitor(of course with new adapter power charge)..problem solved :D