# Touchpad stops working when charger is plugged in

Tags: touchpad, adapter, charger

I have a Dell latitude E6320. When I plug in a new dell charger it chargers the battery but the touchpad stops working. When I unplug the charger the touchpad works just fine. I plug in a universal charger it charges the battery and the touchpad works flawlessly. I've done this on 4 different outlets and I'm getting the same result. The person I bought the dell charger from tells me that "NO MALFUNCTION OF TOUCH PAD CAN BE CAUSED BY ADAPTER" Is this issue coming from within the latop itself or the dell charger?

Comment: All the specifications are same as original adapter?

Comment: Check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/76649/laptop-touchpad-works-incorrectly-when-on-power-supply) answer.

Comment: Yes the specifications are the same.

Comment: I would also check to see if a different power plan is being applied when the charger gets plugged in. If you are unplugged and it is on balanced, but for some reason goes to power saver when you are plugged in, maybe there is a setting that is disabling the keypad. Change power settings to ensure high performance mode is what happens when your charger plugs in and see what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop touchpad response badly when on power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/367979/laptop-touchpad-response-badly-when-on-power-supply)